# Html Code inside an <pre> tag, innerHTML doesnt return all the code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, innerhtml

I want all the code inside an pre-tag but innerHTML or jquery : html() doesnt return all the code. Some things where cut off.
Like doctype und head body tags etc.

```
<pre id="pre">
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html >
        <head></head>
        <body>    
            <div>asdfds</div>
        </body>    
    </html>
</pre>
```

When i alert the innerHTML of the #pre object
it only alerts the div

http://jsfiddle.net/6o8xjtaq/1/

Is there any other possibility to solve this?

Comment: Your `HTML` markup is invalid.

Comment: By making it valid, it works (brings up all the content): http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/6o8xjtaq/2/

Comment: @MelanciaUK I think the OP wants to display the HTML code on screen. In that case, the jsfiddle doesn't work. If you encode the special HTML characters using `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively, I believe it produces the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to do it, use a script

```
<script id="pre" type="text/template">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
    <head></head>
    <body>    
        <div>asdfds</div>
    </body>    
</html>
</script>

$('#pre').text();
```

Comment: Just as an FYI, once IE gets on board you'll be able to use the new [`<template>`](http://caniuse.com/#search=template) element for this. :)

Answer (score 2):

Replace `<` and `>` with `&lt;` and `&gt;` so you can get it as wanted, yet not invalid html.

```
<pre id="pre">
&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;
    &lt;html &gt;
        &lt;head&gt;&lt;/head&gt;
        &lt;body&gt;    
            &lt;div&gt;asdfds&lt;/div&gt;
        &lt;/body&gt;    
    &lt;/html&gt;
</pre>
```